# Jquery - Publish and Subscribe?

Tags: javascript, events, jquery, publish-subscribe

Is there such a thing as publish and subscribe for use with jquery to send msgs from 1 javascript page to another.. Using the same idea behind ajax publish and subscribe?

I would like to use the pattern for communication between pages, i have been using a javascript framework lately but recently converted back to jquery and would love to continue using this.

Any ideas where i should start? and which implementation to use if more than 1 exists..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is a simple JS toolkit that makes working with the DOM easier.

What you need is something like [strophe](http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/). It uses [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) via [BOSH](http://xmpp.org/tech/bosh.shtml). There is a [video](http://jsconf.blip.tv/file/2327793/), where the creator describes it.

Another option is the [Bayeux](http://svn.cometd.com/trunk/bayeux/bayeux.html) protocol. There are [implementations in Dojo and jQuery](http://cometd.org/documentation).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is just a library providing set of utility functions. It is not a programming language. It is not Ajax.

Ajax is a design pattern. It is not a programming language. It is not a library.

Ajax publish-subscribe is just a more specific design pattern that uses the Ajax pattern.

There is no reason it can't be implemented using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for an implementation of the bayeux protocol written in jquery.

A comet plugin that uses the bayeux protocol can be found [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Comet)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the observer pattern to synch the UI?
I think [this](http://google-ajax-examples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/customevents/jquery.html) should help you

Have a look at the code behind
basically when you click on the check boxes on top the behaviour of the link changes
the code is very small 
I love it

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://laharsub.codeplex.com. This is an open source project that provides publish/subscribe capability using HTTP APIs and comes with a jQuery extension that provides usable OM for Ajax applications.